# Vue.js how to configure a component before loading them in template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, graphql, hook

I have a vue single file template, where I am doing some data fetching (a JWT token) and using that token to make a second request to a graphql endpoint. The Provider Component in my template uses that JWT Token and gets passed a :client property which  should be set up with the JWT Token beforehand (before it is getting rendered in the template) like so: `<Provider :client="strapiClient">`  .However, I don't know how to do this step before rendering my components....
What is the best approach? Should I do the fetching and configuration outside of my App or inside with methods and hooks?
I am still quite new to vue.js...

```
<template>
    <Provider :client="strapiClient">
        <Query query= "{ questionDomains { name, description, question_topics {name,description, question_items {name, description}}}}"
        v-slot="{ data, fetching }">
        <div v-if="fetching">Is Fetching ...</div>
        <div v-else>
            <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
        </div>
        <span>{{jwtStrapi}} </span>
    </Query>
    </Provider>

</template>

<script>
import { Provider, createClient, Query } from 'vue-gql'
// import axiosStrapi from '../components/Helpers/axios'
import axios from 'axios'
// import myImportedQuery from '../graphqlQueries/strapiquery.graphql';

const strapiRoot = 'http://localhost:1337/'
const strapiToken = await axios.post(strapiRoot + 'auth/local', {
    identifier: 'test@strapi.io',
    password: process.env.VUE_APP_STRAPI
})
let strapiClient
    if (strapiToken) {
        strapiClient = createClient({
        url: strapiRoot + 'graphql',
        context: () => {
            return {
                fetchOptions: {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `bearer ${strapiToken}`
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    } else {
        strapiClient = createClient({
            url: strapiRoot + 'graphql'
        })
    }

export default {
    components: {
        Provider,
        Query
    },
    methods: {
        init: async function () {
            this.jwtStrapi = await this.getStrapiToken()
            // console.log('jwtStrapi:', jwtStrapi)
            // this.getStrapiClient(this.jwtStrapi)
        },
        getStrapiToken: async function getStrapiToken (url = strapiRoot + 'auth/local', data = {}) {
            const resp = await axios.post(url, {
                identifier: 'admin@strapi.io',
                password: process.env.VUE_APP_STRAPI_PW
            })
            if (resp.data.jwt) {
                return resp.data.jwt
            }
            return null
        },
        getStrapiClient: async function () {
            const token = await this.getStrapiToken()
            if (token) {
                this.strapiClient = await createClient({
                    url: strapiRoot + 'graphql',
                    context: () => {
                        return {
                            fetchOptions: {
                                headers: {
                                    Authorization: `bearer ${this.jwtStrapi}`
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                return this.strapiClient
            } else {
                this.strapiClient = await createClient({
                    url: strapiRoot + 'graphql'
                })
                return this.strapiClient
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.init()
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
            strapiClient,
            jwtStrapi: null
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a v-if on the `Provider` component so that it only loads once the `strapiClient` variable has loaded.

```
<Provider v-if="strapiClient" :client="strapiClient">
    <Query query= "{ questionDomains { name, description, question_topics {name,description, question_items {name, description}}}}"
        v-slot="{ data, fetching }">
        <div>
            <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
        </div>
        <span>{{jwtStrapi}} </span>
    </Query>
</Provider>
<div v-else>Is Fetching ...</div>
```